# VueJS Filter Array Based on Input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) application and I'm trying to filter an array based on an input from a form.

The problem is my array `autocomplete` isn't getting populated with the visitors that match the query of the first name.

My HTML

```
<input class="input" placeholder="First Name" v-model="visitor.first" @keyup.enter="searchVisitors">
```

My Vue Instance

```
new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    previousVisitors: [],
    autocomplete: [],
    visitor: {}
  },

  mounted() {
    axios.get('/visitors/all').then(response => this.previousVisitors = response.data);
  },

  methods: {

    searchVisitors(){
      var q = this.visitor.first;
      this.autocomplete = this.previousVisitors.filter(item => {return item.firstName === q});
      console.log(this.autocomplete);
    }
   }
});
```

I can confirm the repsonse from the axios which is currently populating the `previousVisitors` array contains the `firstName` of each previous visitor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's not working as you expect?

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry. It's the array "autocomplete" it's not populating the array based on the first name.

Answer (score 2):

Your `v-model` is set to `visitor.first` but you are filtering based on `firstName`.

Change your code to use `v-model="visitor.firstName"`.

There are some other issues that could cause problems later. First you are dynamically adding a value to `visitor`. That falls into a [change detection caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) and that value will not be reactive. You should initialize that value.

```
data: {
  ...
  visitor:{firstName: ''}
}
```

Moreover, you should really use a computed value for the filter. Here is a complete example.

```js
console.clear()

const visitors = [{
    firstName: "bob"
  },
  {
    firstName: "mary"
  },
  {
    firstName: "susan"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Phillip"
  },

]


new Vue({

  el: '#app',

  data: {
    previousVisitors: [],
    visitor: {
      firstName: ''
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    // axios.get('/visitors/all').then(response => this.previousVisitors = response.data);
    setTimeout(() => this.previousVisitors = visitors)
  },
  computed: {
    autocomplete() {
      return this.previousVisitors.filter(v => v.firstName === this.visitor.firstName)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input class="input" placeholder="First Name" v-model="visitor.firstName"> {{autocomplete}}
</div>
```